# Linking static build of Log4cxx on linux fails to find symbols

Tags: linux, static, linker, log4cxx

I've build Log4cxx statically on OpenSuse 12.3, however when I attempt to build it in my Qt project it fails at link time. Depending on the order of apr, apr-util and log4cxx the error varies, however this is what I believe is some of the most relevant link errors if I build with this order **unix:!macx:LIBS+=-L$$LOG4CXX_PATH/lib -lapr-1 -laprutil-1 -llog4cxx**:

```
../../../External/Linux/static/log4cxx/lib/liblog4cxx.a(objectptr.o): In function `log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrBase::exchange(void**, void*)':
```

objectptr.cpp:(.text+0x124): undefined reference to `apr_atomic_xchg32'
../../../External/Linux/static/log4cxx/lib/liblog4cxx.a(stringhelper.o): In function`log4cxx::helpers::StringHelper::toInt64(std::string const&)':
stringhelper.cpp:(.text+0x5d0): undefined reference to `apr_atoi64'
../../../External/Linux/static/log4cxx/lib/liblog4cxx.a(pool.o): In function`log4cxx::helpers::Pool::Pool()':
pool.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `apr_pool_create_ex'
../../../External/Linux/static/log4cxx/lib/liblog4cxx.a(pool.o): In function`log4cxx::helpers::Pool::~Pool()':
pool.cpp:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to `apr_pool_destroy'

Answer (score 0):

> -lapr-1 -laprutil-1 -llog4cxx

This order of libraries is wrong. To understand why, read [this](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).